# keepAspectRatio(true) breaks resizing

Tags: magento-1.9, image

i have placed the following code in my template files, in order to resize some custom category images

```
$image = new Varien_Image($imagePath);
$image->constrainOnly (true);
$image->keepAspectRatio (false);
$image->keepFrame (false);
$image->quality (90);
$image->resize($width, null);
$image->save($rszImagePath);
```

The code works fine and images are resized properly. But as soon as I set **keepAspectRatio** to **true**, no resizing is being applied to images.

Why is this happening and what can I do to fix it?

Answer (score 1):

Just a quick thought: 
when you are using

```
$image->keepAspectRatio (true);
```

try to use resize as

```
$image->resize($width);
```

and then Height of image should be calculated properly with keeping aspect ratio

Comment: Resizing still not working when I apply these settings

Answer (score 0):

I have tested next code with all three cases of image resizing and all three cases works well for me - see [screenshot](https://api.monosnap.com/rpc/file/download?id=5hXWufdzmNgQXn7U6Epucn7CiifFpO) :

```
$imagePath = 'media/catalog/category/pic.png';
$rszImagePath1 = 'media/catalog/category/1pic.png';
$rszImagePath2 = 'media/catalog/category/2pic.png';
$rszImagePath3 = 'media/catalog/category/3pic.png';
$width1 = 100;
$width2 = 200;
$width3 = 300;


$image = new Varien_Image($imagePath);
$image->constrainOnly(true);
$image->keepAspectRatio(true);
$image->keepFrame (false);
$image->quality(90);
$image->resize($width1, null);
$image->save($rszImagePath1);

$image = new Varien_Image($imagePath);
$image->constrainOnly (true);
$image->keepAspectRatio (true);
$image->keepFrame (false);
$image->quality(90);
$image->resize($width2);
$image->save($rszImagePath2);

$image = new Varien_Image($imagePath);
$image->constrainOnly (true);
$image->keepFrame (false);
$image->quality (90);
$image->keepAspectRatio (false);
$image->resize($width3, null);
$image->save($rszImagePath3);

echo "<img src='/{$rszImagePath1}' /><img src='/{$rszImagePath2}' /><img src='/{$rszImagePath3}' />";
```

so if your new, resized image is not generated at all - maybe you have issue with folder permissions to save resized images OR you have `$rszImagePath` variable with wrong path inside.

If you have new image generated, but not resized - maybe some code/server issue prevent resizing images of exact file format. Try to use other format of image (png, jpg) and/or check `php_gd` library installed on your environment